# Re-alignment of panels CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, user-interface

I have 4 panels in my page. At a time (depending on certain conditions) either 1,2,3 or all 4 panels are displayed. I want the panels to re-align themselves so that there is no empty space for the panels which are not present.

How can I do this?

EDIT: If all panels are visible then it will look like this :
http://ibin.co/1zrkoFfExnRZ

If suppose Pannel 3 is hidden it will look like this :
http://ibin.co/1zrkcO4vTjHW

Comment: If browser compatibility is not a concern you can use CSS3 Flex-box order property to realign the remaining elements. See http://umaar.github.io/css-flexbox-demo/

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Hi Sunil ,I drew some pictures on paint to explain my requirement but my reputation here isn't allowing me to post them.Is there some place I could upload it to ?

Comment: You may create a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/ for other to review and help you.

Comment: cannot upload images here..is there some place i could upload images ?

Comment: Can you upload working/incomplete copy of your existing code or something similar as a sample on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: The code in in c# (.aspx)

Comment: You may share the front end code and explain the logic and your approach.

Comment: Can the images be accessed ? (please see edit )

Comment: Someone's downvoted the question now..what's wrong people..I already have single digit rep.. :P

Comment: Sunil - did you see the images  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
 
.rowitem {
 
  background: #ff0000;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #fff;

}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="rowitem">01</li>
  <li class="rowitem">02</li>
  <li class="rowitem">03</li>
  <li class="rowitem">04</li>
  
</ul>
```